# Lua: Yield error: attempt to index a nil value (local 'f')

Tags: lua

I'm completely unfamiliar with Lua and I need to work with some Lua code.

I have the following method where I pass in a file and I want to read the contents of that file as a string.

```
function readAll(file)
    local io = require("io")
    local f = io.open(file, "rb")
    local content = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    return content
end
```

For that, I'm getting:

```
Lua: Yield error: [string "myFile.lua"]:101: attempt to index a nil value (local 'f')
```

The error appears on this row:

```
local content = f:read("*all")
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: accoridng to this https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html it can return nil in case of error. Examples fille or directory doesn't exists or permisions prevent the file from be opend

Comment: That message does not come from the Lua library. What program are you using the embeds Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that `io.open` failed. To see why, try

```
local f = assert(io.open(file, "rb"))
```

or

```
local f,e = io.open(file, "rb")
if f==nil then print(e) return nil end
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I get: `Lua: Yield error: attempt to call a nil value (global 'assert')`. I'm guessing I should import some library containing `assert`?

Comment: @octavian, I don't know why `assert` is not defined. Try the second form.

Comment: You're right, that underlying file does not exist. You wouldn't happen to know what I need to import to use `assert`?

Comment: @octavian, `assert` is a standard Lua function. It should be available but it seems that the program that is hosting Lua has chosen to remove it.